# Ngx-datatable not showing data

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Ngx-datatable is not showing my data fetched from an endpoint.

Template file:

```
<ngx-datatable
      class="material p-4"
      [rows]="rows"
      [columns]="[
      { name: 'Case Title', prop: 'title'},
      {name: 'Location of Incidence', prop: 'location'},
      {name: 'Date of incidence', prop: 'dateOfIncidence'},
      {name: 'Description', prop: 'description'},
      { name: 'No of Victims', prop: 'numberOfVictims' },
      { name: 'No of Perpetrators', prop: 'numberOfSuspects' },
      {name: 'Action', prop: 'id'}]"
      [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
      [headerHeight]="50"
      [footerHeight]="50"
      rowHeight="auto"
      [externalPaging]="true"
      [count]="page.totalElements"
      [offset]="page.pageNumber"
      [limit]="page.size"
      (page)="setPage($event)"
    >
</ngx-datatable>
```

Class file:

```js
export class CriminalCaseListComponent implements OnInit {
   form: FormGroup;
   page = new Page();
   rows = Array<IncidenceReportResponse>();
   ColumnMode = ColumnMode;

   constructor(
     private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
     private criminalCaseService: CriminalCaseService,
   ) {
     this.page.pageNumber = 0;
     this.page.size = 10;
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
       incidence: ['']
     });
     this.setPage(this.page);
   }

   search() {
     console.log('search');
   }

   setPage(pageInfo) {
     console.log(pageInfo);
     this.criminalCaseService.getResults(this.page).subscribe(pagedData => {
       pagedData = pagedData[`results`];
       this.rows = pagedData;
       console.log(this.rows);
    });
  }
}
```

The data shows when logged in the browser console but not showing on the ngx-datatable.

[image]

Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

## ISSUE(S)

### Issue 1:

From [[externalPaging]="true" causes rows to disappear?](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/391#issuecomment-268876616)

> You need to set the count property to the total number of rows. If you have the count property set to 0 at the top, within your subscribe method you should set it to the length of the results returned.

And based on provided source code,

```
 [count]="page.totalElements"
```

I don't see you assign the total number of rows to `page.totalElements`. Hence it is **0** and the `ngx-datatable` will not show any records.

---

### Issue 2:

Your pagination does not work correctly after fixing 1st issue as you don't retrieve the selected page number and pass it to the service.

---

### SOLUTION(S)

### Solution for Issue 1

1. Assign `pagedData.page` back to `this.page` to update `this.page.totalElements` value.

```
this.page = pagedData.page;
```

---

### Solution for Issue 2

1. In `ngOnInit`, you should pass object with `offset` to `setPage`.

```
this.setPage({ offset: this.page.pageNumber });
```

2. Retrieve current page number with `pageInfo.offset`.

```
this.page.pageNumber = pageInfo.offset;
```

Your component should be as below:

> criminal-case-list.component.ts

```
export class CriminalCaseListComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      incidence: ['']
    });
    this.setPage({ offset: this.page.pageNumber });
  }

  ...

  setPage(pageInfo) {
    this.page.pageNumber = pageInfo.offset;
    this.criminalCaseService.getResults(this.page).subscribe(pagedData => {
      this.page = pagedData.page;
      this.rows = pagedData[`results`];

      console.log(this.rows);
    });
  }
}
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9g7wkh)

---

References:

1. [Server-side Paging](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#server-paging)
2. [Server-side Paging (Source code)](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/paging/paging-server.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. It's there any way to add an action dropdown button at my action column passing the id into a function?  @Yong Shun

Comment: You are welcome. You may accept this answer if it helps you. I think you are recommended to create another question for your new question. Looking forward to your next question.